# Bitmaps to Rgb48

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm converting a panel to bitmap image, and I did it with the following code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim bmp = New Bitmap(Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height)
Me.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))

PictureBox1.Image = bmp

End Sub
```

After converting the image I'm assigning it to picture box as you see by the code.
Now the problem that I have is that the image is not clear it is blurry.

While searching for HQ(High Quality) conversion in vb library I found rgb32 and rgb48 but they didn't described it for VB or C#.

How could I do that conversion?
Or another source by which the image become HQ, or the conversion to be done in HQ?

Comment: rgb48 sounds like overkill, it enables millions of maths on every single pixel without any data loss. check this page:  http://anti-grain-geometry.1086185.n5.nabble.com/AGG-Example-for-using-rgb48-td141.html

Comment: Changing the pixel format will not have any effect.  Images get blurry when they are displayed with a size that's different from their original size.  Pixels need to be stretched when you display it larger, pixels disappear when you display it smaller.  Set the PictureBox.SizeMode property to Normal and it will be razor-sharp.  Always avoid resizing images that contain text or lines, photos are normally okay.

Comment: Thnx Hans Passant.  You are right, I stretched the image.  Now the picture box is showing the image is sharp, but it gets blurry again when i send it for printing? How should I control it over there?

Comment: Thnx ufomorace the link seems useless to me? I didn't understood single code over there. it dosen't look like for C#.net or VB.net.

Comment: You have to account for DPIs, screens are generally 96 DPI but printers at least 300 DPI so when you print it and scale it to your paper size it will get blurry; solution is to augment the DPIs of your image.